# How to get data from separate worksheets displayed in a single separate worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I am working on a spreadsheet in Microsoft excel 2010. In the spreadsheet I have 3 worksheets. These are known as:

- 1st
- 2nd
- Cases

Now in the 1st and 2nd Worksheets, there is a table at the bottom which contains case details. In the Cases worksheet there is a case table as well but it's empty. What I want to do is the data from both 1st and 2nd Worksheet be automatically inserted in the Cases worksheet table.

How can this be achieved? I have tried consolidation by category by clicking on "Consolidate, selecting the relvant lables and data from the 1st and 2nd worksheet, and added them and clicked ok but it gives me message saying no data was consolidated.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet which can be downloaded:

[Spreadsheet](http://ge.tt/8M6G0Hx/v/0)

Can you give me any suggestions on this or can somebody try and apply my spreadsheet onto an excel document and see if they can get it working?

P.S I know the 2nd Worksheet has blank data in its Case summary table, but this table can consist some data in the future.

Thank You

Comment: You should upload your Excel file [somewhere else](http://ge.tt/) or you will get maaany access requests. Or you have to set the permission to public?

Comment: @nixda Thanks for the link and comment, I put the spreadsheet on that file uploaded you have showed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this formula into the cell `B4` of the sheet "Cases":

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK('1st'!B25)),'1st'!B25,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'2nd'!R" & (ROW($B4)-(COUNTA('1st'!$B:$B)-COUNTA('1st'!$B$1:$B$24))-4+25) & "C" & COLUMN(B4),FALSE))),INDIRECT("'2nd'!R" & (ROW($B4)-(COUNTA('1st'!$B:$B)-COUNTA('1st'!$B$1:$B$24))-4+25) & "C" & COLUMN(B4),FALSE),""))
```

Copy the formula to the other cells in the worksheet; the relative addresses will adjust automatically.

---

The formula works like this:

1. Check if there is content in 1st. If yes, copy it.
2. If no, find out how many entries there are in 1st in total. (This is done by using the `COUNTA` function on the whole B column in 1st and subtracting the number of non-empty cells above the actual case data.) Use this information together with the current cells's number to find out the location of the cell that has to be copied from 2nd.
3. Create the address of the cell and use the `ISBLANK` function on the `INDIRECT` function with that address to check if the cell is empty.
4. If it is not, use the `INDIRECT` function again to display it. If it is empty, just display an empty string.

---

While this works, it's somewhat of a mess and - depending on the number of cases - may cause performance troubles because the use of lots of `INDIRECT` functions is pretty slow.

I'd recommend to use another tool for a task like yours - for example Microsoft Access or some other database tool.

Comment: Hi, yeah this is my cousin's spreadsheet who asked me to help him on this. Tbh I was thinking when looking at it that it would be easier if in database software (especially when I am more suited in databases). I will try your theory and hopefully it works. I will probably try to get the spreadsheet working and send it to him and then build an Access database version for better use. I will update you on what is happening when trying your solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am just having one little issue, it is not able to display anything under the "Case Summary" column when I copy the formula in B4 and then drag it to all rows and columns. Do you know why this is? Also what I find strange is when I do drag the information across, the cells under "Open/Closed" and "Case Number" suddenly isn't merged as it should do, it goes back to being two separate cells, I have to manually merge them again. Do I need to include something like this in the formula?

Comment: You should copy the formula to each column in the first row manually (i.e. select the first column's cell, press Ctrl+C, move to the next column's cell, press Ctrl+V, move to the last column's cell, press Ctrl+V). Drag the whole row to all rows and columns then.

Comment: Hi, I actually tried this earlier , but it states that it can't paste it. It states cannot change part of a merged cell.

Comment: Ah right. You'll have to manually adjust the formula then. Simply replace all the column references that do not start with a `$` (e.g. `B25` or `B4` but not `$B4`) with the character of the right column and put each resulting formula into the three cells of the first row.

Comment: Ok cool this is working now. Thank you very much for your help. Can I ask out of curiosity, what does & "C" & mean in your formula?

Comment: Also if you don't mind (I already marked your answer anyway), just one last thing, If I wanted to add a 3rd worksheet to formula, then do I copy the 2nd IF(NOT(..., change 2nd to 3rd and then include this somewhere in the formula or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Well, it would get way more complicated, because you'd have to count all the entries in 2nd as well and use this to calculate the location of the data that should be copied from 3rd. The formula will have a basically unmaintainable length then. I'd really consider using a database tool or at least some VBA macros for that then.